# Open fragment from another fragment- Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

..In others fragments this works ok.

```
                Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new Fragment_2();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

But in the onclick event

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment  implements
Button btnuevaventa;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
btnuevaventa=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.bt_nuevaventa);
        btnuevaventa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new Fragment_2();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            }
        });
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

LogCat

```
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09003d (com.example.appcreativeventas:id/frame_container) for fragment Fragment_Inicio_Tab{420f42b0 #1 id=0x7f09003d}
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-01 16:50:53.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5555):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handling this wrong, you want to load fragments via your Activity hosting them, not from other fragments... so you use an interface to tell the Activity to execute the code, since in this case R.id.fragment_container is not an id in the Fragment currently. Try something like:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment 
    Button btnuevaventa;
    ClickCallback mCallback;
    public interface ClickCallback{
        void buttonClicked();
    }

    @Override 
    public void onAttached(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallback = (ClickCallback) activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        btnuevaventa=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.bt_nuevaventa);
        btnuevaventa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mCallback.buttonClicked();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then in your Activity implement the interface:

`Activity implements ClickCallback`

```
@Override
public void buttonClicked(){
    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = new Fragment_2();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

}
```